# Drupal Subtheme regions and customization

Tags: theming

I am subtheming a Drupal base theme and adding custom regions to it. One of the custom regions is a menu bar which has say n number of items that redirect to basically the menu item pages.

Now each of these pages, I can foresee regions that do not necessarily adhere to the existing set of regions and custom regions. Basically each page has it's own unique set of custom regions. Which basically is leaving me confused as to how I can separately customize each page given that all pages on Drupal adhere to its' theme's regions.

I hope I am nailing the question here correctly, ask me to elaborate anything that you are not able to understand.

Thanks,

Parijat

Comment: I'd look into using regions for the glue that holds your website together, and rely on blocks to customize what's on each page.  If that doesn't work, then you will have to create a page-PATH-GOES-HERE.tpl.php for each page which seems highly unproductive.

Comment: If each of your pages have a completely different layout, you might go with panel nodes, a module that is packaged with [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels)